# GC operation types in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

With using `perf_hooks` we can get a some information about our garbage collection in NodeJS. We can use it like below with using `PerformanceObserver` which call on every garbage collect (?).

```
        const obs = new perf_hooks.PerformanceObserver(list => {
            console.log(list.getEntries()[0]);
        });
        obs.observe({ entryTypes: ['gc'] });
```

Here is also response from console.log:

```
PerformanceEntry {
  name: 'gc',
  entryType: 'gc',
  startTime: 1150138386.4544,
  duration: 0.08009982109069824,
  detail: { kind: 4, flags: 0 }
}
```

I am trying to find information on the web about what `detail.kind` is in this response. Could someone explain to me what it is?

I found that in NodeJS there are a four kinds of gc:

```
perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_MAJOR
perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_MINOR
perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_INCREMENTAL
perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_WEAKCB
```

ref(https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/perf_hooks.html#performanceentrykind)

but what does each of these types mean?

Thanks for any help!

PS: `duration` determines how long the operation was performed?

Answer (score 6):

See [the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/dabda03ea9ef4baab20e3a377a753174475eb468/src/node_perf.h#L63) where these constants are defined.

> `perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_MAJOR`

A "major" (=full-heap mark-sweep-compact) GC cycle (or more specifically: the atomic pause at its end).

> `perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_MINOR`

A "minor" (young generation only, aka "scavenge") GC cycle.

> `perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_INCREMENTAL`

An incremental marking step. A typical major GC cycle performs dozens or hundreds of these before entering the final atomic pause.

> `perf_hooks.constants.NODE_PERFORMANCE_GC_WEAKCB`

Invoking weak handle callbacks.

> `duration` determines how long the operation was performed?

Yes, that's what the word "duration" tends to mean.